# How can I protect a national patent abroad if I have missed the deadline for an international (PCT) application?

Tags: pct, internatioinal

My father has a patent, registered about 10 years ago, but only in our home country - he has never made a PCT filing. Now, a company from another country is interested in that technology. How can we sell/license it to them? Is it impossible to get a patent in their country because the local patent is too old?

Answer (score 1):

**Is it impossible to get a patent in their country because the local patent is too old?**

Correct: you are unfortunately out of luck.

The current patent is now prior art for all countries, so that a new application in another country would lack novelty. Moreover, you are well past any deadlines for claiming priority (which must be done within 12 months of the first filing).

**How can we sell/license it to them?**

This would be based on the laws of your jurisdiction. Typically this just requires a contract, but may require the assignment/licence to be recorded at the patent office.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I guess the second question should have ended with "without getting ripped off". What the company wants to do is get access to technology for testing first but I guess once they have it there will be nothing stopping them from using it without paying us anything, correct?

Comment: @Olzhas I don't really have a good answer for that, as I fear that is more of a question of negotiating a suitable contract, rather than a patent matter. I would definitely suggest contacting a lawyer in your jurisdiction to discuss how to safeguard your interests.